# Как заменить все единицы в массиве на двойки?

Tags: python, массивы

Как заменить все единицы в массиве на двойки?
Надо из этого `a = [1, 5, 1, 6]` сделать это `a = [2, 5, 2, 6]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте **списковое включение** и **тернарный оператор**:

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 6]
a = [2 if x == 1 else x for x in a]
```

Comment: Интересно, оказывается можно проще.

Comment: @Tehnorobot питон такой язык, что обычно всегда можно ещё проще чем думаешь )

Comment: но зачастую это простота аукается нечитабельностью

Comment: Это не замена, а создание нового списка =р

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего вы имели в виду немного не то, что написали, и вариант со списковым включением вам действительно подходит. Но все-таки, в образовательных целях полезно будет сказать, что использование спискового включения создаст новый объект списка, а не заменит значения в старом. Если понимать ваш вопрос буквально, и вы хотите именно заменить значения в изначальном объекте, то ответ будет примерно такой:

```py
a = [1, 5, 1, 6]

for i, value in enumerate(a):
    if value == 1:
        a[i] = 2

print(a)  # [2, 5, 2, 6]
```

Использование встроенной функции `enumerate` позволяет в каждой итерации цикла получать не только значение из итерируемого объекта, но и его индекс. Это удобнее, чем использовать счетчик.

На практике лучше так, конечно, не делать, т.к. изменять объект, по которому итерируешься - это в 99% зло.

Answer (score 1):

про очевидные способы уже написали, добавлю еще один не вполне очевидный:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [1, 5, 1, 6]
# заменяем все 1 на "а", 5 на "b", 6 на "c"
a = pd.Series(a).replace({1:'a',5:'b',6:'c'}).to_list()
print(a)  # ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, через цикл пройтись по элементам и заменить:

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 6]

count = 0
for i in a:
    if i == 1:
        a[count] = 2
    count += 1
print(a)
```

Можно через генератор:

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 6]

a = [int(str(x).replace('1', '2')) for x in a]
print(a)
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 5, 2, 6]
```

Я бы порекомендовал вам изучить методы [списков](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html) и [строк](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html)

Comment: Спасибо, а если надо изменить цифру на букву? 
Например, заменить все единицы на букву "а"?

Comment: @worgodd тогда в первом случае пишите `a[count] = 'a' `, а во втором - `.replace('1', 'a')`

Comment: Благодарю. Второй способ отлично подошел